# Remove u' from a mongodb list

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a script and I want to remove `u'domain'` and `u` from the list

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient()
db = client.domains
collection = db.domain
find_document = collection.find({},{'domain': 1, '_id':0})

data = list(find_document.limit(2))

{myIds.push(myDoc.domain.str)})
print (data)
```

The result is :

```
[{u'domain': u'allegacyhsa.org'}, {u'domain': u'americanhelpinghands.org'}]
```

I want to print only the domain like :

```
['allegacyhsa.org','americanhelpinghands.org']
```

Without `u` and `{`

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: The `u` is a presentational thing of Python denoting that it's a unicode string. You don't just "remove" it. I'm guessing you want to produce JSON? Then use `json.dump`.

Answer (score 6):

The `u''` notation indicates that you are getting unicode strings ([Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings)).
You can either:

- pick an encoding when printing (ie: `data[0]['domain'].encode('utf8')`)
- cheat with json: `print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))`

From pymongo doc:

> MongoDB stores data in BSON format. BSON strings are UTF-8 encoded so PyMongo must ensure that any strings it stores contain only valid UTF-8 data. Regular strings () are > validated and stored unaltered. Unicode strings () are encoded UTF-8 first. > The reason our example string is represented in the Python shell as u’Mike’ instead of ‘Mike’ is that PyMongo decodes each BSON string to a Python unicode string, not a regular str."

To retrieve only the domains, convert your data to a list of domain like so:

```
domain_list = [datum.get('domain') for datum in data]

print(', '.join(domain_list))
# prints: allegacyhsa.org, americanhelpinghands.org

print(', '.join('%r' % d for d in domain_list))
# prints: "allegacyhsa.org", "americanhelpinghands.org"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about *extracting the domain values*, not about "removing the u". 
That question is simple to answer:

```
domains = [d['domain'] for d in data]
```

If you now want to format them for printing, you could for example use `join`:

```
print(', '.join(domains))
```